# marginTop vs marginBottom on a each loop for Jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-animate, each, sliding

Hi people I already implementing a movile fixed menu to my site based on jquery but i have a little problem with  marginTop  and marginBottom inside on a each sentence, the marginBottom is not working it seams like something is missing , plz check it out.

On-live example: 
http://www.utxj.edu.mx/menu_example/index.html

My code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
            var d=300;

            $('#navigation a').each(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    'marginTop':'-80px'
                },d+=150);
            });

            $('#navigation > li').hover(function () {
                $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({
                    'marginTop':'-2px'
                },200);
            }, function () {
                $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({
                    'marginTop':'-80px'
                },200);
            }
        );
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
            var d=300;

            $('#navigation2 a').each(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    'marginBottom':'-80px'
                },d+=150);
            });

            $('#navigation2 > li').hover(function () {
                $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({
                    'marginBottom':'-2px'
                },200);
            }, function () {
                $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({
                    'marginBottom':'-80px'
                },200);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Tnx 4 help.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` and `$(function() {` do the same thing; choose one, not both

Answer (score 1):

The margins are doing what they're supposed to be doing. The element is going to grow to accommodate the new size of the animating block, and the rest of the elements will drag along with it.

As a solution, try positioning the elements `relative` to their current position and animating their `top` and `bottom` properties:

```
li {
  position: relative;
}
```